# Android center bottom numberpickers

Tags: android, xml, layout, numberpicker

I'm trying to create two number pickers in android. However i try to center them both at the bottom. I tried to mix up relative and linear layout, but i was not able to fix it.

The images shows how the buttons are placed at the moment. The red squares show how i want the buttons to be displayed.

Hope you can help me.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pvdl.ndwatch.NDwatchActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nd_text"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:background="#00ABCC" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#404041"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/title2"
    android:textColor="#404041"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</RelativeLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/background"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onNDstart"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/custom_button" />

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="Chronometer"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/background"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold" />        

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:entries="@array/shutter_times"
     />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:entries="@array/nd_values"
    android:gravity="bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide the full xml for your layout for it to be meaningful (ie parent elements of your NumberPicker elements)

Comment: i have provided the full xml now

Answer (score 1):

Change your xml to this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...> 

     ....

     <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="2" >

      <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/shutter_times" />

      <NumberPicker
       android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:entries="@array/nd_values" />
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want a space between the buttons just add a `paddingRight` to the `left button` and the same value to the `paddingLeft` of the `right button`.

Hope this helps.